# Why do you need to apply hash over DH shared key?

Tags: hash, diffie-hellman, keys, key-exchange, key-derivation

I`ve read multiple times that it is not safe to use the shared key resulted from DH key exchange directly and that you need to do a KDF or hash over it and then use the result as a key. Why is it not safe to use the shared key directly?

Comment: Do you have a link to an example? Besides security a reason might be to adjust for different length requirements or possible bias in the binary format of the result.

Comment: may be this is the dupe [Decisional Diffie-Hellman: compute Legendre symbol of $g^{ab}$ from $g^a$ and $g^b$?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/31378/18298)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, see 1.1. on this [The Decision Die-Hellman Problem](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/papers/DDH.pdf) by Dan Boneh

Comment: A more interesting question would be: for a group of order multiple of a prime $q>2^{255}$, would it be computationally possible to distinguish from random the low-order $\left\lceil\log_2 q\right\rceil-128$ bits of the shared secret?