# How does the Legendre symbol reveal if $g^a$ is odd or even for Finite Field Diffie-Hellman

Tags: diffie-hellman, group-theory

According to wikipedia(markdown is striped below) for [Decisional Diffie–Hellman assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decisional_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_assumption):

> the DDH assumption does not hold in the multiplicative group $Z(p)$,
> where $p$ is prime. This is because if $g$ is a generator of $Z(p)$, then
> the Legendre symbol of $g^a$ reveals if  a is even or odd.

For example I have  $p=23$, $g=2$ and $a=13$ than how do Legendre symbol reveal that  $2^{13}$ is even or odd?

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149112/discussion-on-question-by-pacman-how-does-the-legendre-symbol-reveal-if-ga-is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Since $g$ is generator then it is not square](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/31379/18298), otherwise cannot generate the group (See the bottom theorem). Therefore, as being a $\text{QNR}$, it's Legendre symbol is $−1$; $$\left(\frac{g}{p}\right) = -1 \tag{1}\label{r1}$$

Now, consider $g^a \bmod p$ and the [Legendre calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol#Definition)

$$\left(\frac{g^a}{p}\right) \equiv (g^a)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \pmod p \quad \text{ and } \quad\left(\frac{g^a}{p}\right) \in \{-1,0,1\} \tag{2}\label{r2}$$

So, it can be $1$ or $-1$. Let's find out how to determine.

Now, [Legendre is Multiplicative on it's top argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol#Properties_of_the_Legendre_symbol). I.e.

$$\left(\frac{ab}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{a}{p}\right)\left(\frac{b}{p}\right)\tag{3}\label{r3}$$

$g^a$ means multiply $g$ by $a$-times; combine (\ref{r1}) and (\ref{r2})

$$\left(\frac{g^a}{p}\right) = \underbrace{ \left(\frac{g}{p}\right)\cdots \left(\frac{g}{p}\right)}_{a-times} = \underbrace{ (-1)\cdots (-1)}_{a-times} = (-1)^a \tag{4}\label{r4}$$

- If parity of $a$ is even, then the Legendre is $1$
- If parity of $a$ is odd, then the Legendre is $-1$

Keep in mind that we don't need to determine $a$ here ( that is dLog and hard), we just use the result of the Legendre ( Eqn. \ref{r2}) to determine the parity with the fact that $(-1)^x= 1$ if $x$ is even, and $(-1)^x= -1$ if $x$ is odd.

Similarly, we can find the parity of $g^b$.

Now, we know the parity of $a$ and $b$ then we can find the parity of $ab$, thus this will leak the Legendre of $g^{ab}$ without knowing $g^{ab}$ by using Eqn. \ref{r4}.

---

**Theorem**: for an odd prime $p$, a generator $g$ cannot be Quadratic Residue. i.e. $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) \neq 1$

***Proof 1:*** For prime $p$ we have $\varphi(p)=p-1$ is even and we know that the multiplicative group $\pmod{p}$ has order $\varphi(p)$.

**Let assume that** $g$ is a square, i.e. $g=x^2$, then $x^{p-1}= g^{(p-1)/2} =1 \pmod{p}$.

On the other hand, if $g$ is a generator of the multiplicative group then it cannot have smaller power than $\varphi(p)$ equal to 1. i.e have $g^k\not=1\pmod{p}$ for $0<k<p-1$.

This is **contradiction**, so a generator $g$ cannot be a square.

***Proof 2:*** If we assume that half of the elements are $\text{QR}$ and half are $\text{QNR}$, then using the fact that if we multiply a $\text{QR}$ with $\text{QR}$ then the result is $\text{QR}$, and this implies, a $\text{QR}$ cannot generate all the elements of the multiplicative group.

---

**Note on the reverse of the theorem** : The theorem states that being $\text{QNR}$ is a necessary condition, however, it is not sufficient. [The number of generators of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is studied and turns out to be $\varphi(\varphi(n))$](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numbertheory/gen.html). If we consider the $\mathbb{Z}_{571}$, then there are $\varphi(\varphi(571))= 144 < 285 = 570/2$ generators, so not every $\text{QNR}$ is a generator.

---

**Example:** Consider the $\mathbb{Z}_{571}^*$, where 571 is a prime number and $*$ indicates we consider the multiplicative group with the invertible elements.

Now, use the below SageMath code ([try online](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1kdGKgzAQRd8D-YehT0mxpbYshYIf0Fc_QMhs0yAuMYy-7N_vOLpbV61P472Zew8JRSjg45prVfJwj70PnjpD0WqlVWCtNGeZE9WxN-HY0sOTsTNt11Ab_WfDcsiAV3cZzCVW5LTrOk_90oKigEMuPredL1o1YZhmxyqXCdC6jp3fwuDGksS7J63qJ0jOEH7TCvgTC3LQyn91HubqaZz_KpKjuv-G9gkDCse7JOnIfxdBxAUivkXEFyLCmDJVTpT4jxI3KV8rK0Lhw2TXpttztMDvJ3_7DnHj1SrD23b5dsYccsuWBIK83ebOD_xqoOE=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==))

```
rn = 571
R = Integers(rn)

g = R(2)

print(g.order())

print("kronecker(g, rn)", kronecker(g,rn))

assert kronecker(g,rn) == -1

a = 23
kga = kronecker(g^a,rn)
print("kronecker(g^a, rn)", kga)

ap = 0
if kga == -1:
    ap =  1 
else :
    ap = 0
    
print("parity of a = ", ap)

b = 33
kgb = kronecker(g^b,rn)
print("kronecker(g^b, rn)", kgb )

bp = 0

if kgb == -1:
    bp =  1 
else :
    bp = 0

print("parity of = ", bp)

print("parity a*b =", ap*bp)


print("kronecker(g^ab, rn)", kronecker(g^(a*b),rn))

assert ((-1)^(ap*bp) ) == kronecker(g^(a*b),rn)
```

to test the claims ( remove the prints and make a loop to test more with `from random import randrange`, `a = randrange(rn)`, and `b = randrange(rn)`).

Note that SageMath uses [Kronecker Symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_symbol) which is a generalization of the Legendre Symbol that allows non-primes.

Comment: how does using of subgroup of prime order prevent this leak?

Comment: That easy if you can restrict the group into only QR or k-th residues. That's the point of achieving DDH.