# Determining the Parity of Exponent b in Modular Exponentiation Given Three Known Values

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruence

I have three numbers x, a, and c, where both a and c are odd numbers. The number x is the output of the following function:

$$
x = a^b\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\mod{c}
$$

I am attempting to determine whether the input exponent, b, was an odd or even number based on the knowledge of the three values, a, c, and x. Is there a way to deduce the parity of the exponent b using this information?

Comment: Hint: consider adding in the Q your thoughts about the [Jacobi symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol) $\left(\frac a c\right)$.

Comment: And note that, parity doesn't help to solve DLog. It is just a leak as in [DH](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/108268/18298)